Why other characters are showing in telegram notification

Telegram notification shows html code along with the messages

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706034/using-html-in-telegram-bot

How did you install telegram?

@ArchismanPanigrahi Through app centre

try clearin the .cache dir

Try the native package instead of snap https://telegram.org/dl/desktop/linux
